# He emptied his pockets of loose change. (meaning of 'of')

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> He emptied his pockets of loose change.

My native language which is not English wants to rewrite the sentence as this:

He got rid of loose change from his pockets. Or, He emptied his pockets (from loose change).

Does the 'of' mean 'from'?

The pattern is like 'deprive A of B', 'rob A of B' and it is a little weird that why the direct object B comes later using 'of'

Answer (score 2):

> He emptied his pockets of loose change.

means the same thing as

> He removed all loose change from his pockets.

Your alternative:

> He emptied his pockets from loose change

Is not natural in standard English, at least not in the US or UK.
More generally,

> He emptied X of Y

means that he took all the Y out of X. It may or may not imply that Y was the only thing in X. It does imply that at least some Y was present.